# Defective Item Probability

Tags: probability

A car has two major subsystems. Let us define the following events based on the subsystems $A$ and $B$.
$A$: First subsystem is good; ̿: first subsystem is defective
$B$: second subsystem is operational; : second component is defective.
 
Tests have yielded the following results: $P(A) =0.8$, $P(B \mid A)=0.85$, $P(B \mid \neg A) = 0.75$.
Determine the probability that:
a) The second subsystem is good and operational.
b) At least one of the subsystems is good
c) The first subsystem is good given that the second one is good as well.
d) The first subsystem is good given that at most one of the subsystems is good.

for a) I used Bayes theorem, ie., $P(B) = P(B \mid A)P(A) + P(B \mid \neg A)P(\neg A)$.  I also assumed that $P(\neg A) = 1 - P(A)$, but I could not proceed. Can someone help me?

I calculated $P(\neg A) = 1-P(A) = 1-0.8 = 0.2$; Now 
$$P(B) = 0.85 \cdot 0.8 + 0.75 \cdot 0.2 = 0.83$$

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Did you mean to write $\neg A$: first subsystem is defective?  Did you mean to write $\neg B$: second subsystem is defective?  Also, please show us your actual calculations for part (a).  You may find it useful to read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: -A and -B are probabilities that systems the first and second systems are defective respectively. I calculated P(-A) =1-P(A) = 1-0.8 = 0.2; Now P(B) = 0.85*0.8 + 0.75*0.2 = 0.83

Comment: Your calculation of $P(B)$ is correct.  For the second question, use $$P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$$

Comment: Thanks. Why didnt I  think of it that way. I also used another method where I had some doubts. i.e. if K is the event at least one is good. P(K) = P(AB) + P(-AB) + P(-BA) = P(B/A)P(A) + P(B/-A)P(-A)  + P(-B/A)P(A). But P(-B/A) was not given so I calculated it using P(-B/A) = 1 - P(B/-A) which I wasnt very sure of. But it gave the same answer as P(AUB).

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if it is true or not, please check it.

a)P(B)=you have already found,

b) is mentioned as P(AuB) you can do a) and b)

c) P(A\B)= 0.85*0.8/0.83=0.819

d) P(A\B')=(P(B'/A)*P(A))/ P(B')= ( (1- P(B/A))*P(A) ) / (1-P(B)) = (1-0.85)*0.8/(1-0.83) = 0.704

i hate latex!